# SignalR connection to Azure not working (.net core 3.1)

Tags: azure, .net-core, signalr

Am trying to connect my App with Azure SignalR, but does not seem to establish connection.

It all works fine when I use in my basic config file and run the program locally:

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

But when I change it to Azure like this (I hardcoded the key here)

```
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR("Endpoint=https://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=<MYKEY>;Version=1.0;");
```

I get errors on the client side saying

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

and

> "Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Internal Server Error"

I managed to get the full server Log file below. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.
I can still chose to run SignalR by default and not use the Azure one, but I have thousands of calls on SignalR and Azure seems to explain using their service would be faster.

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:61663/" for site "Traveller" application "/"
Successfully registered URL "https://localhost:44380/" for site "Traveller" application "/"
Registration completed for site "Traveller"
IIS Express is running.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubProtocolResolver[1]
      Registered SignalR Protocol: json, implemented by Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[1]
      Starting HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[7]
      Starting transport 'WebSockets' with Url: https://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=3ecd8966-8daa-4086-9814-c31f11ba7e66.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[1]
      Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=3ecd8966-8daa-4086-9814-c31f11ba7e66'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[1]
      Starting HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[7]
      Starting transport 'WebSockets' with Url: https://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=3809c62f-7960-4596-af76-f96589bc9e27.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[1]
      Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=3809c62f-7960-4596-af76-f96589bc9e27'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[1]
      Starting HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[7]
      Starting transport 'WebSockets' with Url: https://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=3bfd6373-814e-4f54-a86f-0f187e34ea55.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[1]
      Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=3bfd6373-814e-4f54-a86f-0f187e34ea55'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[1]
      Starting HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[7]
      Starting transport 'WebSockets' with Url: https://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=f128631e-ff15-4882-82a8-9aeaf47db2ee.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[1]
      Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=f128631e-ff15-4882-82a8-9aeaf47db2ee'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[1]
      Starting HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[7]
      Starting transport 'WebSockets' with Url: https://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=ebab1e46-a273-4e83-8649-39aad83c18ce.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[1]
      Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=ebab1e46-a273-4e83-8649-39aad83c18ce'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller
Now listening on: http://localhost:61663/
Now listening on: https://localhost:44380/
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'Traveller.Controllers.DefinitionController.Index (Traveller)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Definition"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller Traveller.Controllers.DefinitionController (Traveller).
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[19]
      Started transport.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[19]
      Started transport.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[19]
      Started transport.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[19]
      Started transport.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[19]
      Started transport.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[18]
      Transport 'WebSockets' started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[18]
      Transport 'WebSockets' started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[18]
      Transport 'WebSockets' started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[18]
      Transport 'WebSockets' started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[18]
      Transport 'WebSockets' started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[3]
      HttpConnection Started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[3]
      HttpConnection Started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[3]
      HttpConnection Started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[3]
      HttpConnection Started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[3]
      HttpConnection Started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[13]
      Received message from application. Payload size: 4.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[13]
      Received message from application. Payload size: 4.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[13]
      Received message from application. Payload size: 4.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[13]
      Received message from application. Payload size: 4.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[13]
      Received message from application. Payload size: 4.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[12]
      Message received. Type: Binary, size: 48, EndOfMessage: True.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[12]
      Message received. Type: Binary, size: 48, EndOfMessage: True.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[12]
      Message received. Type: Binary, size: 48, EndOfMessage: True.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[12]
      Message received. Type: Binary, size: 48, EndOfMessage: True.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[12]
      Message received. Type: Binary, size: 48, EndOfMessage: True.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[11]
      WebSocket closed by the server. Close status NormalClosure.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[11]
      WebSocket closed by the server. Close status NormalClosure.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[11]
      WebSocket closed by the server. Close status NormalClosure.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[11]
      WebSocket closed by the server. Close status NormalClosure.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[11]
      WebSocket closed by the server. Close status NormalClosure.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[4]
      Receive loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[4]
      Receive loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[4]
      Receive loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[4]
      Receive loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[4]
      Receive loop stopped.
crit: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[24]
      Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000. Id: 3bfd6373-814e-4f54-a86f-0f187e34ea55
crit: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[24]
      Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000. Id: f128631e-ff15-4882-82a8-9aeaf47db2ee
crit: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[24]
      Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000. Id: 3809c62f-7960-4596-af76-f96589bc9e27
crit: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[24]
      Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000. Id: 3ecd8966-8daa-4086-9814-c31f11ba7e66
crit: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[24]
      Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000. Id: ebab1e46-a273-4e83-8649-39aad83c18ce
fail: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.StrongServiceConnectionContainer[2]
      Hub 'NotificationsHub' is now disconnected from '(Primary)https://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net'. Please check log for detailed info.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[4]
      Disposing HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[4]
      Disposing HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[4]
      Disposing HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[4]
      Disposing HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[4]
      Disposing HttpConnection.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[6]
      Transport is stopping.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[6]
      Transport is stopping.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[6]
      Transport is stopping.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[6]
      Transport is stopping.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[6]
      Transport is stopping.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[8]
      Send loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[8]
      Send loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[8]
      Send loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[8]
      Send loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[8]
      Send loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[2]
      Transport stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[2]
      Transport stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[2]
      Transport stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[2]
      Transport stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[2]
      Transport stopped.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[6]
      HttpConnection Disposed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[6]
      HttpConnection Disposed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[6]
      HttpConnection Disposed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[6]
      HttpConnection Disposed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[6]
      HttpConnection Disposed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[1]
      Starting HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[7]
      Starting transport 'WebSockets' with Url: https://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=b81c6688-9239-4342-897f-86c3bd7f7c6d.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[1]
      Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=b81c6688-9239-4342-897f-86c3bd7f7c6d'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[19]
      Started transport.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[18]
      Transport 'WebSockets' started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[3]
      HttpConnection Started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[13]
      Received message from application. Payload size: 4.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[12]
      Message received. Type: Binary, size: 48, EndOfMessage: True.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[11]
      WebSocket closed by the server. Close status NormalClosure.
crit: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[24]
      Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000. Id: b81c6688-9239-4342-897f-86c3bd7f7c6d
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[4]
      Receive loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[4]
      Disposing HttpConnection.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[6]
      Transport is stopping.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[8]
      Send loop stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[2]
      Transport stopped.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[6]
      HttpConnection Disposed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view Index.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[4]
      Executed ViewResult - view Index executed in 235.3981ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/lib/css/bootstrap.css  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.js?2300  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js?2500  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/js/JSKonvaSearch.js?2000  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.js?2400  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/js/signalr/signalr.js?2800  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/js/JSUtils.js?2000  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Traveller.Controllers.DefinitionController.Index (Traveller) in 1169.127ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'Traveller.Controllers.DefinitionController.Index (Traveller)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/js/JSGlobals.js?2000  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession[3]
      Session started; Key:7337807d-0554-d5b7-e2b1-bb23dae40b59, Id:d2077465-8aea-9f6f-2e81-7d3074ea87e2
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/js/JSKonvaSearch.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\js\JSKonvaSearch.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/js/JSGlobals.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\js\JSGlobals.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/js/JSUtils.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\js\JSUtils.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 19.3002ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 59.6407ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 58.1304ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js?2600  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/js/JSKonvaDraw.js?2000  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/lib/js/konva.2.4.2.min.js?2200  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/lib/js/Chart.bundle.v2.7.3.min.js?2800  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/js/JSDashboard.js?2000  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/css/site.css  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/js/signalr/signalr.min.js?2850  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1308.065ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/js/JSKonvaDraw.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\js\JSKonvaDraw.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\lib\js\jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\lib\js\bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/js/JSDashboard.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\js\JSDashboard.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 52.7555ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/js/Chart.bundle.v2.7.3.min.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\lib\js\Chart.bundle.v2.7.3.min.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/js/signalr/signalr.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\js\signalr\signalr.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 40.9507ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 50.1708ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/css/bootstrap.css'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\lib\css\bootstrap.css'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 71.0605ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 155.159ms 200 text/css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\lib\js\bootstrap.bundle.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.js  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/js/konva.2.4.2.min.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\lib\js\konva.2.4.2.min.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.js  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 171.1148ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 101.9239ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/js/signalr/signalr.min.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\js\signalr\signalr.min.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 94.194ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 210.5455ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 217.9566ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/css/site.css'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\css\site.css'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 149.158ms 200 text/css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\lib\js\jquery-3.3.1.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\lib\js\jquery-3.3.1.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 244.3982ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\lib\js\bootstrap.bundle.js'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 80.9432ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 80.7803ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44380/images/image_welcome_background_xsmall.jpg  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/images/image_welcome_background_xsmall.jpg'. Physical path: 'C:\Users\francois.debodinat\Documents\_perso code\ProjectTraveller\Traveller\wwwroot\images\image_welcome_background_xsmall.jpg'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 24.7034ms 200 image/jpeg
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://localhost:44380/hubs/notifications/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/hubs/notifications/negotiate'
crit: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceRouteHelper[1]
      Client negotiate failed: Azure SignalR Service is not connected yet, please try again later.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint '/hubs/notifications/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 48.5865ms 500 
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[1]
      Starting HttpConnection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[7]
      Starting transport 'WebSockets' with Url: https://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=535de32b-cedb-4cda-9959-675e6712f6ac.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[1]
      Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://frenscoservice.service.signalr.net/server/?hub=notificationshub&cid=535de32b-cedb-4cda-9959-675e6712f6ac'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[19]
      Started transport.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[18]
      Transport 'WebSockets' started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[3]
      HttpConnection Started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[13]
      Received message from application. Payload size: 4.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[12]
      Message received. Type: Binary, size: 48, EndOfMessage: True.
crit: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[24]
      Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000. Id: 535de32b-cedb-4cda-9959-675e6712f6ac
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[11]
      WebSocket closed by the server. Close status NormalClosure.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[4]
      Disposing HttpConnection.
etc.
```

Comment: What version of the SignalR client are you using?

Comment: It seems like the most likely reason is indicated by `Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000` when attempting to connect to the Azure SignalR service, I'd recommend checking the SignalR service.

Comment: Hit the limit for free tier, you'd probably need to upgrade to standard

Comment: @KalZekdor am using SignalR version v4.2.2+97478eb6 on client side (both min and js ones). Your point is spot on though, I indeed reached the limit of 20,000 messages yesterday. My application sends a lot more than that, so I will have to minimize the nb of requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happened to me on  the day of my sprint review, when we reached the max message count for our free tier Azure SignalR service. As you can see in your log, you rechead the 20k messages limit.

> crit: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[24]
>         Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000. Id: 535de32b-cedb-4cda-9959-675e6712f6ac
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[11]
>         WebSocket closed by the server. Close status NormalClosure.
>
> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[4]
>         Disposing HttpConnection.

You can just create a new free tier Azure SignalR service and change the key for the new one or upgrade. During our development we just created new ones before it was almost completed and change it for the standard tier.

[image: SignalR pricing tiers]